# Retrieving scalar from excel file

Tags: c#, excel, odbc

I need to populate part of a string with a scalar obtained from an excel sheet: `string myStr = myStr + excelResponce(myStr) ;`
However myStr is continuously updating and there is no need to put either the request data or the string in a list.
I tried (1)odbc adapter to load the full excel file and datarows select() to retrieve the scalar and (2) odbc open-query-close method. Both work, but look inefficient: former has to load in memory the whole xls with resource limitation, latter is not meant for scalars and it suffers from having a dataset loaded with a single row of data.
How to connect to simple structure data ? How to retrieve minimal data in the most efficient way? Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `ExecuteScalar` method, not anything else, so you will load the exact scalar and not a DataSet.

here an example I just copied from the Internet, if you have created a range called myRange1 in excel, assuming that contains only 1 cell with an integer value, here is how to get it:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb; 

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filename = "filename.xls";
            string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filename + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=1;IMEX=1""";

            string sql = "SELECT * FROM myRange1"; 

            using(var conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            using(var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
            {
                conn.Open();

                Int32 myReturnScalar = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            }
        }
    }
}
```